# How to dynamically move seekbar from another seekbar in android?

Tags: android, seekbar

I need to dynamically move 2 seekbars. While the user moves one, the other will have to move also accordingly to the values of the first.
I've created 2 seekbars but they move independent from each other, how can i "link" them so, for ex. the second seekbar moves 1/10th of the first?
Thanks

`seekBarSM.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBarSM, int progress,
         boolean fromUser) {
  seekBarSMValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
   }
   @Override
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBarSM) {
        }
   @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBarSM) {
    }
});`

seekBarSF.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBarSF, int progress,
         boolean fromUser) {
  seekBarSFValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
   }
   @Override
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBarSF) {
      }
   @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBarSF) {
      }
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onProgressChanged()` of one, just call `setProgres()` on the other with the value it should change to.

Comment: Any way to work with floats instead of int when setting progress?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to work with some sort of int scale that you can translate your values to.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will try to do that.

Comment: @mbaird Can you answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756044/how-to-set-first-seekbar-process-value-is-to-assign-initial-value-of-second-seek